# Font size not working

Tags: fontsize

I process the code using XeLaTeX. My first line:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,titlepage]{article}
```

Above works. Unfortunately anything other than `12pt` seems to result in a default size (size `10pt` I guess).

So how to set it to like `13pt` or `14pt` ?

P.S. I tried commenting out all other packages to see if there's a conflict somewhere. No luck.

Comment: the standard classes only have 10pt 11pt and 12pt options. Why do you need 14pt (there is a moresize package to extend it). You can of course get other font sizes within the document such as `\large`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I'd like my body text to fill more space. For example in "Word" one can set even size 12.5.

Comment: You can have fonts of any size as I say: `\large` `\huge` `\fontsize{1in}{2in}\selectfont` the options on document class are not for setting up a font size but setting up page layout dimensions: sizes of headings sizes of spaces around displayed equations etc, the default body font is just one small part of that.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you. I wasn't exactly aware of this fact.

Answer (score 1):

Without using any extra packages, stick this in your preamble, perhaps?  (I do not have Xe(La)TeX; this is tested in LaTeX and works, but I can't speak for anything else.)

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\normalsize{%
  \@setfontsize\normalsize{14}{9.0}%
}
\makeatother
```

The first argument is the font size itself; the second is the baseline separation.